# Try to pass 2 variables to php using ajax jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I've been looking to find a way to update some data into my database when execute onclick function.
The idea is to update the value of a button contains the word "Active" and when execute onclick like to update into mysql to "Inactive"
This is the button:

```
$register_status = '<button class="btn btn-success btn_status btn-block" data-status="Active">Active</button>';
```

How to give the data variable so that we can fetch it in PHP using $_POST? The above representation of the data variable shows an error.

***scripts.js***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').click('.btn_status', function(e){
  var button = jQuery(e.target);
        if(button.data('status') == 'Active'){ 

        var data = {id:id, register_status:Inactive};
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           dataType: "json",
           url: "ajax/updateStatus.php",
           data: data,
           success: function(data) {
                alert("update!");
           }
        });

        }else if(button.data('status') == 'Inactive'){
          alert("nothing");
        }
  });
})
```

***ajax/updateStatus.php***

```
include("db_connection.php");

if(isset($_POST))
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $register_status = $_POST['register_status'];
    $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `register_status` = '$register_status'  WHERE `id` = '$id'";
    if (!$result = mysqli_query($db,$query)) {
        exit(mysqli_error());
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

This is another function to delete. This function is run correctly.

```
function DeleteUser(id) {
        $.post("ajax/deleteUser.php", {
                id: id
            },
            function (data, status) {
                readRecords();
            }
        );
}
```

***deleteUser.php***

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['id']) != "")
{
    include("db_connection.php");
    $user_id = $_POST['id'];
    $query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = '$user_id'";
    if (!$result = mysqli_query($db,$query)) {
        exit(mysqli_error());
    }
}
?>
```

and when do a click I can remove:

```
<li onclick="DeleteUser('.$row['id'].')"><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. If there's a better way to do what I mentioned above. thanks

Comment: Shouldn't Inactive be quoted, or else it's passing along an attempt of a variable?

Comment: yes. It's a variable that I want to pass at php. maybe there is another better option

Comment: Where is Inactive defined in your javascript? Also, try `var_dump($_POST);` to see what it contains

Comment: I check this before. No result..

Comment: `var data = {id:id, register_status:Inactive};` <== missing quotes on 'Inactive'?

Comment: In `data`, where is `id` defined?

Comment: Additionally, your script is susceptible to **SQL Injection**.

Comment: "id" is a value on my database. (id, name, status,...) When exeute my first query I generate a table and one cell contains the button.

Comment: $gulf, so you want to send the string "id" to the PHP, is that correct? Based on what I see, you're PHP is expecting this to be a ID number that is used in the query to find a specific row.

Comment: Why do you need this to be submitted via AJAX? You can achieve the same by using a plain old <form> tag

Comment: I need to send the word "Inactive" to php. The id just to know what row update

Comment: Then you need to quote the word Inactive in your javascript. `var data = {id:id, register_status:'Inactive'};` You also need to make sure that you're grabbing the id value from your button in your javascript, so that it can be passed to your php file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the example, you will want to make some changes:

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
  function updateStatus(id, st){
    $.post("ajax/updateStatus.php", {"id": id, "register_status": st}, function(data, status){
       console.log("Update Success", data, status);
       readRecords();
    });
  }

  $('body').on('click', '.btn_status', function(e){
    var button = $(this);
    updateStatus(1001, (button.data("status") === "Active" ? "Inactive" : "Active"));
  });
});
```

First, using the `click()` as you had, was not exactly the best way to do it. Using `.on()` will be better as it can handle any new or dynamically created items.

This script will require `id` to be defined someplace. The AJAX needs to send the id info to the PHP. The code you posted does not show this, so I am not sure what it's value should be.

**PHP (updateStatus.php)**

```
include("db_connection.php");

if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    $id = (int)$_POST['id'];
    $register_status = ($_POST['register_status'] == "Inactive" ? "Inactive" : "Active");
    $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `register_status` = '$register_status'  WHERE `id` = '$id'";
    if (!$result = mysqli_query($db,$query)) {
        exit(mysqli_error());
    }
}
```

These updates can help prevent SQL Injection. I would advise using [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to further prevent it.

**Update**

If you're button is going to be something like this:

```
<button onclick="ChangeStatus('.$row['id'].') class="btn btn-success btn_status btn-block" data-status="Active">Active</button>
```

Notice that this is only passing in just the `ID` from PHP. If these items will always be "Active", then yes, you can do this with something like:

```
function ChangeStatus(id){
  $.post("ajax/updateStatus.php", {id: id}, function(data, status){ console.log(status, data)});
}
```

With **PHP** like:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] != ""){
  include("db_connection.php");
  $user_id = (INT)$_POST['id'];
  $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `register_status` = 'Inactive'  WHERE `id` = '$user_id'";
  if (!$result = mysqli_query($db,$query)) {
    exit(mysqli_error());
  }
}
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I update the post with another function that it's run. I put the jquery code but not update the value on database

Comment: @GuifIf I have updated my answer. You still need to pass an ID and Status in to the new function. It's based on your other example.

Comment: I update the initial question. I add how to remove a value with the funcidion ***DeleteUser***. Think that the id variable can pass correctly. How would the code be?

Comment: @GuifIf you will notice there that when the link is created, it's passed an ID from PHP: `$row['id']` and that is passed into `DeleteUser()` that is bound to `click` callback. You'lll need to do something similar.

Comment: but inside (for example a function called ChangeStatus) can do this? ```<button onclick="ChangeStatus('.$row['id'].') class="btn btn-success btn_status btn-block" data-status="Active">Active</button>```or how can pass the $row[id] inside the button?

Comment: @GuifIf yes if you wrote a function to do that, yes.